# How to pick </html> </body> tags

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

This is My html :

```
 <div id="tab1" class="tab_content">

 <div id="dvreadmore"><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>


<title>&nbsp;</title>


<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


</head>


<body>

<div>

<p class="dgthreedigest">CL : Where petitioner raised same bills against respondent as well as its sister concern, winding up petition against respondent for non-payment of dues was to be dismissed - [2012] 19 taxmann.com 206 (Delhi)</p>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Please see this URL (http://www.taxmann.com/taxmannflashes/whatsnew.aspx?sid=9578&stype=1)

```
WebResponse res = req.GetResponse();

StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream());


string htmlResp = sr.ReadToEnd();


String htmlBody = "";

if (htmlResp.ToLower().Contains("<div id=\"dvreadmore\">"))
{
     int startIndex = htmlResp.ToLower().IndexOf("<div id=\"dvreadmore\">"); 

     //here i m getting    first  index value
     // but when i pick last indext it awlays give me -1 


     int lastIndex = htmlResp.ToLower().IndexOf("</html>\n</div>");
```

Same thing I did in Java compiler, pick the last index and give certain value, but in C# Asp .Net I'm not able to pick data, it always gives -1 value.

How to pick the last index?

Comment: The last line is looking for the end of the </html> followed by a newline and then a closing </div>. That's not what's in your HTML.

Comment: but i have same way pick de data Using Java and getting value but in C# its given -1 i dont know why thats wat some Problme is coming to display whole data

Comment: i have to display that Much of data CL : Where petitioner raised same bills against respondent as well as its sister concern, winding up petition against respondent for non-payment of dues was to be dismissed - [2012] 19 taxmann.com 206 (Delhi)  same logick works in Java i dont know why its not working in C# while i m able to pick first index its givng corrct

Comment: maybe HtmlAgilityPack or any other html parser will help you more to read html contents

Answer (score 0):

you must take **lastIndex** as

`int lastIndex = htmlResp.ToLower().IndexOf("</html>\r\n</div>");`

or

`int lastIndex = htmlResp.ToLower().IndexOf("</html>" + Environment.NewLine + "</div");`

it returns 23195